# Why do kubernetes kube-api server need etcd-keyfile and kubelet-client-key

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

As I understand kube-api server acts as a client when communicating with ETCD and Kubelet. Both ETCD and Kubelet act as servers for kube-api. With secure environment (two way SSL authentication), kube-api server needs the ETCD and Kubelet certificates and the CA certificate. What I don't understand is why do we need to provide the private keys of ETCD (etcd-keyfile) and Kubelet (kubelet-client-key) while configuring kube-apiserver.yaml ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [etcd uses X.509 mutual TLS authentication](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.7/Documentation/op-guide/security.md#example-2-client-to-server-authentication-with-https-client-certificates) in kubernetes, so the apiserver needs to be able to prove it has ownership over the *client certificate* that is presented to the server, and that happens via private key

There are [other authentication options](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.7/Documentation/op-guide/authentication.md#using-etcdctl-to-authenticate) for etcd, but kubernetes doesn't use them, and it's unclear if the apiserver even offers a non-TLS authentication option for connecting to etcd, even if you wanted to

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel I was confused over mutual authentication initially, so what we provide on api-server.yaml are the api-server client certificates generated for ETCD and Kubelet. Since api-server have the ownership on certs (as you mentioned) the keys are also provided on the api-server.yaml.